# script to map network drive

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, scripting

I want to be able to connect to a (wifi) network hard drive from my laptop, but only occasionally. If I use the "Map a network drive" command in WinXP explorer, I have to put in the drive's IP address and name, then the router name and its password. Too much to remember!

I'm looking for a way of scripting this activity (in any language), something like:

```
map Z: \\10.0.1.1\DRIVENAME "ROUTERNAME\PW"
```

I don't particularly care what language the script is written in. BTW, I'm aware of the DOS 'subst' command, but I don't think I can use that in this case because of the password protection.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

use the `net use` command:

```
net use Z: \\10.0.1.1\DRIVENAME
```

**Edit 1:** Also, I believe the password should be simply appended:

```
net use Z: \\10.0.1.1\DRIVENAME PASSWORD
```

You can find out more about this command and its arguments via:

```
net use ?
```

**Edit 2:** As Tomalak mentioned in comments, you can later un-map it via

```
net use Z: \delete
```

Comment: And to unmount it, the slightly confusingly named delete option "net use z: /delete"

Comment: The password can't simply be appended, only the user name can.

Comment: in the "net use ?", it says: NET USE [devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]...  Appending the password with a space should work according to the docs.

Answer (score 13):

Does this not work (assuming "ROUTERNAME" is the user name the router expects)?

```
net use Z: "\\10.0.1.1\DRIVENAME" /user:"ROUTERNAME" "PW"
```

Alternatively, you can use use a small VBScript:

```
Option Explicit
Dim u, p, s, l
Dim Network: Set Network= CreateObject("WScript.Network")

l = "Z:"
s = "\\10.0.1.1\DRIVENAME"

u = "ROUTERNAME"
p = "PW"

Network.MapNetworkDrive l, s, False, u, p
```

Answer (score 4):

[Tomalak's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563028/script-to-map-network-drive/563046#563046) answer worked great for me (+1)

I only needed to make alter it slightly for my purposes, and I didn't need a password - it's for corporate domain:

```
Option Explicit
Dim l: l = "Z:"
Dim s: s = "\\10.10.10.1\share"
Dim Network: Set Network = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Dim CheckDrive: Set CheckDrive = Network.EnumNetworkDrives()
Dim DriveExists: DriveExists = False
Dim i

For i = 0 to CheckDrive.Count - 1
  If CheckDrive.Item(i) = l Then
    DriveExists = True
  End If
Next

If DriveExists = False Then
  Network.MapNetworkDrive l, s, False
Else
  MsgBox l + " Drive already mapped"
End If
```

Or if you want to disconnect the drive:

```
For i = 0 to CheckDrive.Count - 1
  If CheckDrive.Item(i) = l Then 
    WshNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive CheckDrive.Item(i)
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not map the network drive but deselect "Reconnect at logon"?  The drive will only connect when you try to access it.  Note that some applications will fail if they point to it, but if you're accessing files directly through Windows Explorer this works great.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [net use](http://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/net-use-command/) command

Answer (score 1):

Here a JScript variant of [JohnB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287311/johnb)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3097624/117347)

```js
// Below the MSDN page for MapNetworkDrive Method with link and in case if Microsoft breaks it like every now and then the path to the documentation of now.
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6(v=vs.84).aspx
// MSDN Library -> Web Development -> Scripting -> JScript and VBScript -> Windows Scripting -> Windows Script Host -> Reference (Windows Script Host) -> Methods (Windows Script Host) -> MapNetworkDrive Method

var WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject('WScript.Network');
function localNameInUse(localName) {
    var driveIterator = WshNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives();
    for (var i=0, l=driveIterator.length; i < l; i += 2) {
        if (driveIterator.Item(i) == localName) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function mount(localName, remoteName) {
    if (localNameInUse(localName)) {
        WScript.Echo('"' + localName + '" drive letter already in use.');
    } else {
        WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive(localName, remoteName);
    }
}

function unmount(localName) {
    if (localNameInUse(localName)) {
        WshNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive(localName);
    }
}
```